# Should a sentence have a comma before the quotation when the quotation is given an indefinite article?

Tags: commas, indefinite-articles, quotations

See the following:

> I heard the man shout out a, “Good luck, lad!”

Should there be a comma after *a*? Thanks!

Comment: Nope.  No comma.

Comment: This is how the [_Smithsonian Magazine_](https://www.smithsonianmag.com/history/hi-yo-silver-away-51426976/) handled the punctuation in a functionally similar situation involving a very famous (on U.S. radio and TV) tagline: "A fiery horse with [the] speed of light, a cloud of dust, and a hearty 'Hi-Yo Silver!" ... The Lone Ranger!" As Hot Licks says, no comma.